# How to schedule a local notification two specific days of the week?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I want to schedule a notification to be fired twice a week:

```
let gregorian = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)
let now = Date()

[2, 4].forEach { day in 
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Notif title"
    content.body = "Comment"
    content.sound = .default
    var components = gregorian.dateComponents([.year, .month, .weekdayOrdinal, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: now)
    components.hour = 11
    components.minute = 25
    components.second = 0
    components.weekdayOrdinal = day

    let date = gregorian.date(from: components)!
    let triggerDaily = gregorian.dateComponents([.weekdayOrdinal, .hour, .minute, .second], from: date)
    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerDaily, repeats: true)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "test", content: content, trigger: trigger)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Oops: \(error)")
        } else {
            print("Notification created!")
        }
    }
}
```

But instead of being fired once on monday and once on wednesday, it gets called two times each day.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help.

Comment: How many times are you executing this code?

Comment: @ielyamani I'm executing this piece of code once, `Notification created!` appears twice in the console as expected with the for-loop. But instead of having only one notification popping up at 11:25, I get two of them.

Comment: The issue here is that you need to use a different identifier for each Notification

Answer (score 0):

You can use .weekday instead of .weekdayOrdinal . According to Apple document

> .weekday = A weekday or count of weekdays.
>
> .weekdayOrdinal = weekday ordinal or count of weekday ordinals.
>   Weekday ordinal units represent the position of the weekday within the
>   next larger calendar unit, such as the month. For example, 2 is the
>   weekday ordinal unit for the second Friday of the month.

Try this

```
 let triggerDate =  Calendar.current.dateComponents([.weekday,.hour,.minute], from: date as Date)
triggerDat.weekday = day[index]

 let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: triggerDate,
                                                            repeats: true)
```

Comment: I tried replacing all the `.weekdayOrdinal` with `.weekday`, but I'm getting the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

because of `foreach` loop your code schedule two notification with the same identifier. while your code is getting execute the 2nd loop cycle overwrite the request.

I did some R&D and refine your code a bit. On my side, it works perfectly.

Please try the code mention below.

```
func setNotification() {
    let days = [2,4]

func ScheduleNotification(index:Int){
    let calendarComponents = NSDateComponents()
    calendarComponents.hour = 11
    calendarComponents.minute = 25
    calendarComponents.second = 0
    calendarComponents.weekday = days[index]

    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Notification title"
    content.body = "your message here."
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default

    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: calendarComponents as DateComponents, repeats: true)
    let identifier = "UYLLocalNotification\(days[index])"
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: identifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: { (error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        }else{
            if index == 0{
                ScheduleNotification(index: 1)
            }
        }
    })
}
ScheduleNotification(index: 0)
}
```

call this function in your `viewdidLoad` method like.

```
self.setNotification()
```

i hope it will save your time.

Answer (score 0):

Simply change the name of `identifier` of each notification inside the `foreach(_:)` to something like test2, test4, i.e.

```
[2, 4].forEach {
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "title"
    content.body = "body"
    content.sound = .default

    var components = DateComponents()
    components.timeZone = TimeZone.current
    components.weekday = 11
    components.hour = 25
    components.minute = 0
    components.second = $0

    let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: components, repeats: true)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "test\($0)", content: content, trigger: trigger)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Oops: \(error)")
        } else {
            print("Notification created!")
        }
    }
}
```